# Javascript RegEx not returning false as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

Not a big user of RegEx - never really understood them! However, I feel the best way to check input for a username field would be with one that only allows Letters (upper or lower), numbers and the _ character, and must start with a letter as per the site policy.  The  My RegEx and code is as such:

```
var theCheck = /[a-zA-Z]|\d|_$/g;
alert(theCheck.test(theUsername));
```

Despite trying with various combinations, everything is returning "true".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is saying "does `theUsername` contain a letter, digit, or end with underscore".

Try this instead:

```
var theCheck = /^[a-z]([a-z_\d]*)$/i; // the "i" is "ignore case"
```

This says "`theUsername` starts with a letter and only contains letters, digits, or underscores".

Note: I don't think you need the "g" here, that means "all matches".  We just want to test the whole string.

Comment: Bonus, OP should search for common regex patterns. Pretty sure others have gone thru that pain

Comment: Does this force the first character to be a letter?

Comment: @tip2tail: It does now, it didn't before.

Comment: @Alfabravo - as I alluded to in  my first post I'm really effin dumb when it comes to RegEx. I did search, copied and pasted for the last hour and a half but got nowhere fast. In 10 mins here I'm now light years ahead in terms of my project. Thanks tho! ;o)

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,})$
```

To explain the entire pattern:

```
^ = Makes sure that the first pattern in brackets is at the beginning
() = puts the entire pattern in a group in case you need to pull it out and not just validate
a-zA-Z0-9_ = matches your character allowances
$ = Makes sure that this must be the entire line
{3,} = Makes sure there are a minimum of 3 characters. 
    You can add a number after the comma for a character limit max
    You could also use a +, which would merely enforce at least one character match the second pattern. A * would not enforce any lengths
```

Comment: Overkill in the length of the second block. A '+' should do (we don't know how long should it be)

Comment: @Alfabravo I am actually about to add some explanation. However, I would hope it would be at least 2+ characters

Answer (score 1):

Use this as your regex:

```
^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

Comment: Wouldn't that match a blank string?

Comment: Oh yeah... Oops. I also forgot about "it must start with a letter".

Comment: @jahroy BTW, this will not deal with the it must start with, and that the entire line must be correct